# How to make phpstorm display line numbers by default?

Tags: ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, line-numbers

How to make phpstorm display line numbers by default?
Couldn't find that option. It's kind of annoying to turn them on manually for each page.

Comment: you can search on top of the settings pane. just write "line number" and you will find it

Comment: I can't believe PhpStorm doesn't have this enabled by default. What developer doesn't want line numbers most of the time? (*not really a question*) Anyways, good question, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's actually really annoying that it's not on by default. I'd assume every developer unfamiliar with their product has ended up on this page at some point.

Comment: Maybe we are all supposed to get to the point as programmers where our chi "inner energy" helps us see line numbers even when they're not there. Thank you IntelliJ!!!

Comment: Other IDE's don't have it enabled by default either, not sure why... Monitor size is generally not exactly that limited these days, and line numbers are used constantly, by me anyways.

Answer (score 656, accepted):

`Settings` (or `Preferences` if you are on Mac) | `Editor` | `General` | `Appearance` and check `Show line numbers`.

Comment: You can get to settings on Windows with `ctrl`+`alt`+`s`, or `file` -> `settings`

Comment: PHP 8.0.3 `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> Check `Show line numbers`

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + A on Windows lets you search all options.  Just hit it and type `line numbers` and you can enable and disable them.

Comment: You can use Ctrl + Shift + A and you can find any settings.

Comment: Don't have Appearance with PhpStorm 10.0.4.

Answer (score 125):

Just now found where is it on **Windows**. Its `View` -> `Active Editor` -> `Show Line Numbers` (changes only for current document) and `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Appearance` -> `Show Line Numbers` (for all documents)

For **Mac Version** go to `PhpStorm` -> `Preferences` in menu.
In the preference window go to `IDE settings` -> `Editor` -> `Appearance` -> `Show Line Numbers` (To change setting for all documents)

OR if you want to quickly set show line number **PER CURRENT WINDOW** even **easier** - right click on the long white column (where breakpoints are set) then select Show Line Numbers.

[image]

Red dot on the screenshot is a place where you have to click

Comment: For version 8.03 on Windows to change it for all documents, it is now under `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> `Show Line Numbers`

Comment: Works on Linux too

Answer (score 52):

All the guys are right. I am just bringing the the current soultion with the images.

1. Go to `File`-> `Settings`

[image]

2. In the box in the top right corner type in `line numbers`, just below that choose `Editor`->`Appearance`, from the right checkboxes, find `Show line numbers` and check it.
3. After that hit `Apply` and `OK`

[image]

That should do the trick.

My version of PhpStorm is **6.0.3**

Answer (score 15):

If you're on a Mac:

PhpStorm -> Preferences... -> Editor -> Appearance -> **Show Line Numbers**

[image: main menu]
[image: inner menu]

Comment: This is the best answer for MAC! Currently (in PhpStorm 8) I found it in `PhpStorm -> Preferences... -> Editor -> Appearance -> General -> Show Line Numbers`

Answer (score 15):

just double tap '**Shift**' 
and search for '**Line Numbers**'
and there you will see a toggle option **on** or **off**

Answer (score 8):

In PHPStorm 8 this setting is no longer under 'Appearance' but now in:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Appearance -> Show line numbers

Comment: I don't find any Appearance under Editor.

Comment: You need to open General submenu and then you will find Appearance -> Show line numbers

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps:

- Click on File->Settings->
- In the Settings dialog box Expand Editor under IDE Settings
- Click Apperance - > select Show line numbers.
- Click Apply->Ok.

Comment: Your answer is being automatically shown by Google. http://puu.sh/lV9s9/e0be334c42.png

Answer (score 7):

[image: Simplest solution for line numbers in php storm..There are many other solutions but i think A big picture a good from 1000 words.]

Simplest solution for line numbers in php storm..There are many other solutions but i think A big picture a good from 1000 words.

Answer (score 6):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance
check "Show Line Numbers"

This is the current location as of phpStorm 8.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks It worked for me too. The setting is in the right place that has been stated. However I have to restart my PHPstorm to show the line numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Settings -> editor | appearance | Show line numbers

Comment: It has been moved and now exists here in more recent versions

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on left side where line numbers generally show, select "show line numbers"

Comment: This solution has already been provided by @pleerock. Please don't post duplicate answers here.

Answer (score 3):

In PHPStorm 2016: File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > check "Show line numbers"

Answer (score 3):

By  typing `command + shift + A` you will get a search prompt and write `line numbers` . Now you can trigger button `on or off`

[image: phpstorm]

Answer (score 2):

For PhpStorm version 9 on Windows.
`File`→`Settings`→`Editor`→`General`→`Appearence` then check `Show line numbers`

Answer (score 2):

in the top right corner is a search button type show line numbers and you will see a toggle option. this way you never have to do it yourself. :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
File->settings->IDE Settings->Editor->Appearance
```

And just check  the "Show line  numbers" works with 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac version 8.0.1 has this setting here:

PhpStorm > Preferences > Editor (this is in the second section on the left - i.e. IDE Settings NOT Project Settings) > Appearance > Show line numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should go to: File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show Line Numbers

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest version:

PhpStorm **>** Preferences.. **>** Editor **>** General **>** Appearance **>** Show line numbers

[image: PHPstorm line numbers]