# Disable shortcut for quit in phpstorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Shortcut for "Quit PHPStorm" is ⌘Q. Unfortunately, "Q" is just near "S" on french keyboard. Sometimes, I want to save my work, and I quit PHPStorm.

Is there a way to disable that shortcut ?

Comment: there are many questions on stackoverflow about PHPStorm (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086023/how-to-make-phpstorm-display-line-numbers-by-default with 145points) so I think I can ask my question here :)

Comment: `Preferences | Keymap` -- find that action and remove shortcut from it -- should work (sorry, not a Mac user) NOTE: you have to use your own keymap as you cannot edit bundled ones. **P.S.** You can also configure IDE to ask for confirmation before exiting. **P.P.S.** PhpStorm saves all files (or, at very least, remembers all changes) when you exit.

Comment: When I edit (or remove) this action on mac, it as no effect :(. Thanks for your P.S and your P.P.S !

Comment: Since I'm not a Mac user .. I may only suspect that this is a Mac OS controlled shortcut and program cannot override it (or PhpStorm ignores such override). No other ideas (unless, you did not created your own keymap (by cloning bundled one) and attempted to edit bundled ...)

Comment: "I may only suspect that this is a Mac OS controlled shortcut" Me too ! I'm using your "P.S" so it's a average-good solution for me :)

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, this solution might help - https://techpurohit.in/disable-quit-shortcut-phpstorm-macos

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to show a confirmation dialog when you press ⌘Q.

Related post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003485719/comments/360001307519